# Touch coordinates in iPhone landscape mode app

Tags: iphone

I am trying to make this **landscape only** iphone app.

I only use this code for this purpose:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight); }
```

However when I click clip subviews checkbox from interface builder, the view is clipped from the middle.

I also don't receive any touch events from outside of view bounds obviously.

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
CGPoint fingerPos = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self.view];
NSLog(@"%f   %f",fingerPos.x,fingerPos.y); }
```

only prints for coordinates between 20 and 320 for X. But Y works fine.

When i try to modify bounds by hand, everything works fine; View is positioned and shown correctly, printed coordinates are correct, I receive touch from all of the screen except between 0 and 20 for X. So Left side of the screen is unresponsive to touch events for only 20 pixels. Code I use to modify bounds:

```
self.view.bounds = CGRectMake(-180.0f, 0.0f, 680.0f, 480.0f);
```

What might be causing this? Weird!

Comment: Now, I used this:
self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 480.0f, 320.0f);
more logical code :) but still, i don't get any touches between 0 and 20 for X.

Comment: ok, I think it's blocked by status bar. But status bar is hidden. How to overcome this?

Comment: found this: http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/1663-disabling-top-status-bar-application.html

Did the UIStatusBarHidden=true in plist file but still no luck. haaa going crazy here :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, as it is said in the link i've posted in comments, touch events received correctly on the device. So it's a problem of simulator.